# VistaOpenFileDialog does not start with the correct initial directory

Tags: c#, dialog

Reference: [Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.VistaOpenFileDialog](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/):

I'm trying to set Ookii's VistaOpenFileDialog initial directory like this :

```
    VistaOpenFileDialog vfb = new VistaOpenFileDialog();
        vfb.Multiselect = true;
        vfb.Title = "pouet";
        vfb.RestoreDirectory = false;
        vfb.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";
        if (vfb.ShowDialog() ?? false)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(delegate
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < vfb.FileNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileDisplay.Add(vfb.FileNames[i]);                    
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    private void AddFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AddFileDialog));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```

But whatever I try is not working, the dialog never open at first by the initial directory and also never reopen by the initial directory. I can still select a file of folder without problem.

I already tried the following (as test) :

```
vfb.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";
vfb.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\";
vfb.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop).ToString();
```

also tried restoredirectory true or false doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this issue as well. I can't tell why it is not working that way, but I found that if you instead set the `FileName` property to that folder, it will open at the specified path:

```
VistaOpenFileDialog dialog = new VistaOpenFileDialog();
// To show the contents of "C:\", i.e. the parent of "Users":
dialog.FileName = @"C:\Users"
// To show the contents of the "Users" directory:
dialog.FileName = @"C:\Users\"
```